# Objective-c categories

Tags: objective-c, categories

I'm learning Objective-C and now I'm stuck with categories. Here is the code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


    @interface NSMutableArray (NSMutableArrayCategory)

    -(NSMutableArray *)removeLastObject;

    @end

    #import "NSMutableArrayCategory.h"


    @implementation NSMutableArray (NSMutableArrayCategory)

    -(NSMutableArray *)removeLastObject
    {
       return [self removeObjectAtIndex:[self count] - 1];
    }
    @end
```

The problem is that I get

```
Returning void from a function with incompatible result type 'NSMutableArray' *
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Im not familiar with objective c. but i imagine that removeObjectAtIndex returns void. so I would try [self removeObjectAtIndex:[self count] -1];   return self;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to declare `removeLastObject` as returning `void`, not `NSMutableArray`.

```
@interface NSMutableArray (NSMutableArrayCategory)

- (void)removeLastObject;

@end
```

Then the implementation will look like this:

```
- (void)removeLastObject
{
   [self removeObjectAtIndex:[self count] - 1];
}
```

This matches the other mutation methods on `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: Of course, if you're making a category method on an Apple class, you probably want to namespace it somehow. For example, something like `removeLastObject_joh` to ensure it won't conflict with some method defined in the future, in private or in another category.

Comment: You definitely want to call it something different here because `removeLastObject` already exists

Comment: @JeremyP er, right! That, too! It also doesn't raise an exception when `[self count]` == 0 :)

Answer (score 2):

The underlying problem is that `removeLastObject` is already defined and does what you want (so people don't recreate it). Some of the answers here are a little confusing, however, in that they suggest it's ok to use a category to override an existing method (or at least don't explicitly state that you must not do this). You must not do this. It is poorly defined behavior, and in some cases it is completely undefined behavior. You generally should subclass to override a method.

There is an advanced technique called swizzling that will allow you to do this without a subclass, but it is a very specialized and sometimes fragile technique, not for general use.

But in no case should you use a category to override an existing method.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with objective c. but i imagine that removeObjectAtIndex returns void. so I would try

```
[self removeObjectAtIndex:[self count] -1]; 
return self;
```

return self after removing item..